# How to skip building `protoc` when compiling protobuf from source code?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers

When building protobuf from source code, I see some errors as is shown here: [Error when compiling Protobuf for C++ in iOS: "Undefined symbols" and "ld: warning: ignoring file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335349/error-when-compiling-protobuf-for-c-in-ios-undefined-symbols-and-ld-warni?noredirect=1#comment122548676_69335349)

Since those errors seem to be related to protoc only, I am wondering whether I can skip building protoc, because indeed I never need it! (I use protoc from the official website)

I have searched through google and documentation but cannot find any clues. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In protobuf's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/CMakeLists.txt) I see option `protobuf_BUILD_PROTOC_BINARIES` which seems to be related to building `proto` binary. You may try to set this option to `OFF` when configure the project (`cmake -Dprotobuf_BUILD_PROTOC_BINARIES=OFF <other parameters>`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Reasonable, thanks!